# Haskell Simple program pattern matching error

Tags: haskell

If given list of numbers [3,1,4,6,2] -> I increase every odd element by 1 and decrease every even element by 1 I should get [4,0,5,5,3]

my code is

```
change [] = []
change (x:y:xs) = (x+1)(y-1):change xs
```

I write function change with a base case where if list is null it returns null list and then it recursively increases every odd elment by 1 and decrease all even indexed elements by 1 and pushes them back to the list

However I get a pattern matching error. What have I done wrong? And how can this be fixed?

Comment: In addition to the pattern matching problem, I think you're missing a cons (`:`) operator between `(x+1)` and `(y-1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the case of a `List` with one `Int`:

```
change [x]
```

Comment: That will match a list containing a single non-empty list, you need `change [x]`

Comment: not sure what u mean so i change(x:y:xs) to (x:xs) ? why would this fix it

Comment: Note that `x:xs` will also match a list matching `x:y:xs` so it would have to go after the longer pattern.

Comment: Yes, as Lee said, add this as the last case.

Comment: If it's intended to match a list with exactly one element, why not write `change [x]` as Lee suggested? (Or `change (x:[])` if you really must use the `:` directly). Much clearer for each equation to say what it means without relying on ordering where this is easy, and it's conventional to put the base cases above the recursive case.

Comment: Changed it to `[x]` as both @Lee and @Ben think it's clearer. Personally, I prefer having the stop cases after the recursive case as that shows the order of calls.